# Upgrading Nunit(2.6) and specflow(2.1.0) project to latest stable versions

Tags: visual-studio, nunit, upgrade, specflow

I am using following nuget packages:

```
NUnit 2.6.3
Specflow 2.1.0
specflow+Excel 1.4.2
Specflow+Excel : beta 1.4.2
selenium 2.43.1
```

When I am updating these to their latest versions and restart the Visual Studio, the project fails to load with following message:

```
mypath\packages\SpecFlow.2.2.0\tools\TechTalk.SpecFlow.tasks" was not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please upgrade the **SpecFlow.Plus.Excel** 1.4.2 to 1.6.0, then upgrade the SpecFlow to the latest version. You can check the following screenshot and found the SpecFlow.Plus.Excel 1.6.0 depends on SpecFlow.2.2.0 and if you directly update the SpecFlow 2.2.1, it cannot found the dependency and popups the error message that you met. If you firstly upgrade the SpecFlow.Plus.Excel then upgrade the SpecFlow, it works fine and I tested it in my side.
[image]

Comment: Yes, I just happen to figure that out. Before installing SpecFlow I started with SpecFlow.Plus.Excel.  Thanks